# Is MySQL able to optimize: where `indexed_field` IN (<subquery>)?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Why isn't MySQL able to consistently optimize queries in the format of `WHERE <indexed_field> IN (<subquery>)`?

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    t1
WHERE
    t1.indexed_field IN (select val from ...)
    AND (...)
```

The subquery `select val from ...` runs very quickly. The problem is MySQL is doing a `full table scan` to get the required rows from `t1` -- even though `t1.indexed_field` is indexed.

I've gotten around this by changing the query to an inner join:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    t1
INNER JOIN
    (select val from ...) vals ON (vals.val = t1.indexed_field)
WHERE
    (...)
```

Explain shows that this works perfectly -- MySQL is now able use the `indexed_field` index when joining to the subquery table.

My question is: Why isn't MySQL able to optimize the first query? Intuitively, doing `where <indexed_field> IN (<subquery>)` seems like quite an easy optimization -- do the subquery, use the index to grab the rows.

Comment: likely because of how dynamic the subquery is.

Answer (score 1):

No or Yes.

Old versions of MySQL did a very poor job of optimizing `IN ( SELECT ... )`.  It seemed to re-evaluate the subquery repeatedly.

New versions are turning it into `EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )` or perhaps a `LEFT JOIN`.

Please provide

- Version
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE`
- `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: The subquery / tables / explain are rather cumbersome to recreate here, so I'd rather just takeaway the cases in which it can and cannot optimize.  Version is 8.0.17. t1 is a table with a primary key of autoinc INT and some other fields only used in the select.  Does it matter what the subquery is? It seems like no matter what the optimizer should materialize the subquery and use the t1 index to join on it. Some insight into which cases MySQL will / will not optimize would be helpful.